# ToolStripMenuItem: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, multithreading

I created, from the development environment, a multi-level ToolStripMenuItem stack.

Problems:
1) The code (below) is used to preset the values of the toolstrip items. There are two ToolStripMenuitems for which myItem.GetCurrentParent().InvokeRequired does not equal this.InvokeRequired. GetCurrentParent.InvokeRequired produces the correct result one item, this.InvokeRequired works for the other. All other items work properly with either format.
2) If I bypass the preset process and, with the program running, I click on the top-level ToolStripMenuItem, the program crashes with the "Cross-thread" message.

Details:
The form and all the controls on the form are created from the development environment.
Visual Studio creates a startup class that is run statically through             "Application.Run(new cfrmParent());" 
'InitializeComponent() sets up all my controls without any problem.
I instantiate the form with "public cfrmCommand CmdFrm = new cfrmCommand();"
I then have a separate thread execute a CmdFrm.ShowDialog to allow the user to operate controls (and to allow other external processes to update displays on the form). When error #2 occurs, it does so against the ShowDialog command.

When the form loads, I preset the ToolStrip Menu Items. This is where the problems occur. All other controls on the form, and their related code, work properly. If I delete all sub-menu items from the top ToolStripMenuItem, that item works properly.

Suspicion:
My 'guess' of the problem is that Visual Studio does not access toolstrip items, from an upper menu item to a lower, through a proper thread-checking process. When I click on the top-level item, it tries to load the lower level items, which were created on a different thread.

Is a proper solution for me to only create, attach, and preset the lower-level menu items programmatically when the upper level item is clicked on or is there a better way to address this?
Thanks for the help.

My Code to preset menu items:

```
private void WriteMenuItem(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem myItem, string writeValue)
{
    if (myItem.GetCurrentParent().InvokeRequired != this.InvokeRequired)  
    {
        int myTest = 1;}
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new dlgWriteMenuItem(ivkWriteMenuItem), myItem, writeValue);}
    else
    {
        ivkWriteMenuItem(myItem, writeValue);}
}
private delegate void dlgWriteMenuItem(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem myItem, string writeValue);
private void ivkWriteMenuItem(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem myItem, string myValue)
{
    myItem.Checked = (myValue.Trim().ToUpper() == "TRUE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.Invoke(delegate
{
    // Do work
});
```